# CoreBluetooth in Apple Watch Series 2

Tags: bluetooth, watchkit, core-bluetooth, apple-watch, watchos-3

Is it possible to use CoreBluetooth in a WatchKit extension for the new Apple Watch Series 2? Or, exist there other possibilities to connect a third-party watch app to a Bluetooth device without using the iPhone as a middle instance?

That isn't possible for the first Apple Watch, but maybe it has changed with the new Apple Watch.

Edit: CoreBluetooth is supported by Watch OS 4.0 and higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way (yet). CoreBluetooth is still absent in watchOS3.x – hence you would need a wifi device if you want to skip the iPhone.

Update: Please open a rdar (Apple bug report), if you want to see `CoreBluetooth` in a future version of watchOS.

2nd Update: Don't bother opening more bug reports... **it's coming in watchOS 4**

Comment: I did as you suggest and it was closed as "Duplicate of 18716968". Mine was 3157XXXX so it's been there for a while.